# Определение кодировки в C#

Tags: wpf, c#

Здравствуйте! Нужна помощь.

В одной программе раньше для обмена с сервером использовалась кодировка UTF-8, сейчас же нужна UCS-2. Скажите, как мне правильно написать либо конвертер, либо сразу енкодер.

Язык C#, платформа WPF. Используется Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional, по-моему SP1.

Comment: UCS-2 и UTF-16 - сильно разные кодировки. UCS - кодировка с постоянной длиной символа, UTF - с переменной

Answer (score 1):

UCS-2 это предшественник UTF-16, содержащий строго двухбайтовые кодировки. В диапазоне от 0x0000 до 0xFFFF он полностью эквивалентен UTF-16, а все, что вне, недоступно. Соответственно, перекодировать можно двумя способами.

1. Взяв исходную строку в UTF8, каждый символ, который поместится в два байта, положить в итоговую строку.
2. Взяв исходную строку в UTF8, перекодировать ее в UTF16 стандартными средствами C# и пройдя по полученной строке, удалить все не двухбайтовые (суррогатные) кодировки.

Поскольку UCS2 - предшественник UTF16, в сети встречается код преобразования из UTF8 в UCS2 для разных языков, чтобы не писать все с нуля, можно искать по имени функции: utf8toucs2 или utf8_to_ucs2.

Ну, и если известно, что суррогатные кодировки реально не будут использованы (есть ограничение по языкам), то можно взять UTF16.

Comment: А можно ли сразу указать такую кодировку строки?

Comment: При создании строки в конструкторе можно указать нужную кодировку (System.Text.UnicodeEncoding), но это не будет UCS-2, это будет UTF-16.

Comment: А можете показать пример синтаксиса для предопределения кодировки? И за UTF-16 отвечает какое свойство? Unicode? У меня после написания "Encode." доступны UTF-32, UTF7 и UTF8.

Comment: Посмотрите, здесь есть разные варианты: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx